# Magento CE - Store pickup shipping option & transactional email variables / spec emails

Tags: shipping, multistore

we enabled store pickup, actually we enabled "free shipping" and named it Store Pickup.

And we now have the following issues we need to address:

- the standard shipping email contains text explaining how we ship. We now need a depend or if/else statement: pickup text 1, other text 2. How can this be done?
- as I understand there is no other way to do this other than utilizing the "Free Shipping" or "Fixed rate" option. Or am I missing something?

Question: how can we best implement store pickup? (interested in experiences and esp. simple solutions)

Answer (score 1):

There are several paid but not too expensive extensions that offer really nice store pickup shipping methods. Check for `collinsharper`, `magestore` or `aheadworks`.

Explaining how to build a good store pickup module is simply a bit too extensive for an answer

Answer (score 0):

We ended up utilizing this solution (and sticking to the regular Magento flow).

@Sander The extensions look good but all utilize a separate button or flow. Also I think one great one is missing (single location store pickup extension): http://www.magmodules.eu/ready-to-pickup-from-store-e-mail.html

**Solution we ended up using**

1. Add block type variable in transactional email (shipping)

   `{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='emails/storepickup.html' order=$order}}`
2. create new file in custom template folder or base/default

`public_html/app/design/frontend/theme-here/custom/template/emails/storepickup.html`

3. create code like this in `emails/storepickup.html` and change filter & text

`<?php 
$_filter = "store pickup" // wordt to search for in description;
if($order = $this->getData('order')) {
    $_descr = $order->getShippingDescription();
    if (strpos($_descr,$_filter) !== false) {
        echo 'Pick me up please!';
    } else {
        echo "Your order was shipped";
    }
} else {
  echo "Your order was shipped";
}
?>`

Hope it helps.

---

Ps. we also logged two bugs/feature requests to Magento. 1 for a method to [add custom variables more easily](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/767) like (get ShippingDescription or any other) and 2. for a [comparison methods like eq/== for variable matching in transactional emails](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/768). If you think this is a good idea please respon or +1 the issue request.